# find maximum within shifting data range in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner and do not know which terms exactly to search for, so please forgive me if I could easily find help on my problem..

I have a dataframe like so:

```
data <- structure(list(index = 1:25, val = c(1, 5, 2, 34, 65, 2, 5, 6, 
8, 4, 2, 2, 8, 89, 5, 43, 45, 7, 3, 67, 8, 9, 93, 5, 7)), .Names = c("index", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")

 index value
1      1     1
2      2     5
3      3     2
4      4    34
5      5    65
```

I would like to find the maximum value (and name it x1), easy:

```
x1 <- max(data$value)
```

Then I would like to find the maximum value for the range of values "below" x1 (i.e. with an index lower than that of x1) and name it x2:

```
x2 <- max(data$value[which(data$index<data$index[which(data$value==x1)])])
```

Now I'd like to continue like that until I have found all "maximum" values (65, 34, 5 and 1 in this case). I have tried to look into for-loops (or `lapply`?) but I have no idea where to start. Can you give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cummax` for this:

```
## find cummax
cm <- cummax(data$value)
#  [1]  1  5  5 34 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 89 89 89 89 89 89 89 89 89 93 93 93

## find first index of the maximal values
idx <- which(!duplicated(cm))

## bind them together
m <- cbind(idx=idx, max=cm[idx])
m
#     idx max
#[1,]   1   1
#[2,]   2   5
#[3,]   4  34
#[4,]   5  65
#[5,]  14  89
#[6,]  23  93
```